# use jquery to load remote html alt attribute into another page using for loop and array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I am trying to get the information in a image alt attribute from one page (source) and insert it into another page (same server) with javascript/jquery. A for loop will extract source URLs to extract the information from. It works until I get to the jquery load action... I'm looking for a way to extend the id reference of the photo to get the information from the alt attribute on the source HTML page. Please advise and thank you in advance!

-------------------------------- source HTML page...

```
<img id="photo" alt="Text to be loaded into another page" src="pathToImage.jpg">
```

---

```
<script>

countStart = 0;

// Begin loop to write each section from an array reference of page URLs/sources
for (var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {

//  The "replaceURLs" array value/variable yeilds the URL of the pages to extract from
replaceURLs = Array[i].value;  

// write a div where the information will be inserted
document.write('<div id="prodImgAlt' + countStart + '"></div>');  

// jquery load remote HTML
$( "#prodImgAlt" + countStart ).load( replaceURLs + " #photo" );
```

// here is where I'm    getting stuck... I need to modify the "#photo" reference to extend to the information in the img alt attribute on the source HTML page... than that information will be stuffed int the div #prodImgAlt.

```
countStart++;
}; // end loop
</script>
```

Comment: sorry - what is the problem?  What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.each(Array, function (idx, url) {
    var $div = $('<div />', {
        id: 'prodImgAlt' + idx
    }).appendTo('body');
    $.get(url, function (html) {
        var $html = $(html),
            $img = $html.find('img');

        $div.append('<div>' + $img.length + ',' + $img.attr('alt') + '</div>');

        $html.find($img.attr('alt')).appendTo($div);
    }, 'html');
})
```

Comment: Thank you... is there a way to modify the   $( "#prodImgAlt" + countStart ).load( replaceURLs + " #photo" );   to get the img alt?

Comment: I played around with it last night but couldn't get it to work within the whole program.  I'll have to finish the project without it and come back to this a little later.  I'm not that proficient with jquery so this takes some research for me.  I was really hoping there was some syntax I was overlooking for the selector parameter, since the load method I'm already using is so simple - it seems like there should be but my searching isn't turning up any method to drill down that detailed.  I'm really amazed Arun at how you hash this out so quickly and effortlessly!  Nice work!